# Toggle functions on button click

Tags: jquery

Please see below code to toggle between two function when a button is clicked. But the button gets invisible after click and second function is always called. Why!?

```
        $('#btnClick').click(function () {
               $(this).toggle(
                    //$('tr').toggleClass("highlight");
                    function () {
                        alert("Function one called");
                    },
                    function () {
                        alert("second function called");
                });
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: toggle doesn't work like that any more... http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: It never *really* did work as above... With the old `toggle`, that would hook up a new pair of handlers on every click. V. odd indeed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yeah, good point.  I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because toggle(function,function...) is removed in 1.9+ what you should do is something like this

```
var tog = false;
$('#btnClick').click(function () {
    tog = !tog;
    if (tog) {
        alert("Function one called");
    } else {
        alert("second function called");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not `tog = !tog;` ?  Much easier to read (and what you did was incorrect anyway ;)

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, awesome ty :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer, without global variables

```
$('#btnClick').click(function () {
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked') || 0;
    if (clicked % 2 == 0) {
        alert("Function one called");
    } else {
        alert("second function called");
    }
    $(this).data('clicked', clicked + 1);
});
```

Comment: +1, but why not use a bool? Also, you've forgotten to update the stored data.

Comment: I try to minimize utilisation of global variables in every codes ;)

Comment: @ Paul: That wasn't my question. (And note that with the previous answer, it doesn't *have* to be global, if there's something enclosing the code.) You've used a number. Why not use a bool? (Good update on setting the updated value.)

Comment: You don't need to write a complicated code just to toggle, neither do you need any pre-defined function. A bool will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVNwJ/4/)**

try with If condition and you will get as requirment

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="button 1"/>
<input type="button" id="btnClick1" value="button 2"/>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var i=true;
$('#btnClick').click(function () {
    i= !i;
    if (i) {
        alert("2nd function called");
        $('#btnClick1').toggle();
    } else {
        alert("1st function called");
        $('#btnClick1').toggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#btnClick').toggle(function () {
                        alert("Function one called");// work on first click
                    },
                    function () {
                        alert("second function called");// work on second click

        });
```

reference **[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**

**update** for new version of jquery 1.9 + toggle is removed in new version

```
var stat= 0;
$('#btnClick').click(function () {
    stat= !stat;
    if (stat) {
        alert("Function one called");
    } else {
        alert("second function called");
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably because that version of `toggle` was deprecated a long time ago and was removed in v1.9. Also, the docs you've linked to have nothing to do with that old, removed version of `toggle`, which is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).